# Unhandled exception when calling method

Tags: c#, exception

i would like to pass the numbers that are in the list in to the Player class and print them, but when i try to compile its trowing me an exeption. Where is my mistake?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Game
{
    public class Poker
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Player cards = new Player();

        }
    }


    public class Shuffle : Poker
    {
        public static List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();

        public Shuffle()
        {
            for (int runs = 0; runs < 530; runs++)
            {
                int number = random.Next(1, 53);
                if (!numbers.Contains(number))
                {
                    numbers.Add(number);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Player : Shuffle
    {

        private static int cardOne = numbers[0];
        private static int cardTwo = numbers[1];
        private static int cardThree = numbers[2];
        private static int cardFour = numbers[3];


        public static void playerOne()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cardOne);
            Console.WriteLine(cardTwo);
        }

        public static void playerTwo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cardThree);
            Console.WriteLine(cardFour);
        }
    }
}
```

When the crash occures it says: When the crash occures it says: When the crash occures it says:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer fo
r 'Poker.Player' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: In
dex was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collect
ion.
Parameter name: index
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
   at Poker.Player..cctor() in c:\Users\Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects
\PokerProject\TestShit\ShuffleCards.cs:line 42
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Poker.Player..ctor()
   at Poker.Poker.Main() in c:\Users\Pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Po
kerProject\TestShit\ShuffleCards.cs:line 15
Press any key to continue . . .
```

The code is fixed. Runs and compiles now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Game
{
    public class Poker
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Player cards = new Player();
            cards.playerOne();
            cards.playerTwo();
            cards.playerThree();
            cards.playerFour();
        }
    }


    public class Shuffle : Poker
    {
        protected List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        Random random = new Random();

        public Shuffle()
        {
            for (int runs = 0; runs < 530; runs++)
            {
                int number = random.Next(1, 53);
                if (!numbers.Contains(number))
                {
                    numbers.Add(number);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Player : Shuffle
    {
        private static int cardOne;
        private static int cardTwo;
        private static int cardThree;
        private static int cardFour;
        private static int cardFive;
        private static int cardSix;
        private static int cardSeven;
        private static int cardEight;

        public Player()
        {
            cardOne = numbers[0];
            cardTwo = numbers[1];
            cardThree = numbers[2];
            cardFour = numbers[3];
            cardFive = numbers[4];
            cardSix = numbers[5];
            cardSeven = numbers[6];
            cardEight = numbers[7];
        }

        public void playerOne()
        {
            Console.Write("Player one cards: ");
            Console.WriteLine(cardOne + " " + cardTwo);         
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        public void playerTwo()
        {
            Console.Write("Player two cards: ");
            Console.WriteLine(cardThree + " " + cardFour);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public void playerThree()
        {
            Console.Write("Player three cards: ");
            Console.WriteLine(cardFive + " " + cardSix);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        public void playerFour()
        {
            Console.Write("Player four cards: ");
            Console.WriteLine(cardSeven + " " + cardEight);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Compiler errors are **not** the same as exceptions. 2. What's the error you're seeing? 3. Where are you seeing it?

Comment: What is the error? I noticed you have a namespace `Poker` and a class `Poker`. That could give you a problem too. Try change the naming.

Comment: The code compiles: in the error list it says Error 1 No overload for method 'playerOne' takes 0 arguments. But when the exe runs it says system.argumentOutOfRange

Comment: Your 'Shuffle' is not going to give you your cards. You should consider doing a proper fisher-yates shuffle.

Comment: The shuffle works even if its slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method which accepts two ints, and you're trying to call it without passing any arguments:

```
public static void playerOne(int cardOne, int cardTwo)
```

But you call it like this:

```
cards.playerOne();
```

You need to read through your code and take a look at how it works, maybe read some articles of the fundamentals of C#?

I see what you're trying to do. You want to use internal variables in the methods, but you have them in the arguments for the method.

```
public static void playerOne(int cardOne, int cardTwo)
{
    Console.WriteLine(cardOne);
    Console.WriteLine(cardTwo);
}
```

Should be:

```
public static void playerOne()
{
    Console.WriteLine(cardOne);
    Console.WriteLine(cardTwo);
}
```

Comment: Compiles but still crashes and shows an exeption. The type initializer for Poker.Player trew an exeption

Comment: The most helpful thing when something breaks is to know why. The message that pops up when it breaks will tell you exactly what the problem is. In order for us to help you, you should really tell us what that message says word for word. Would you go to the doctor and just say "it hurts"? Or would you te(ll him where, and what kind of pain?

Comment: @KostadinAndonov public class Shuffle //: Poker -- remove Poker

Comment: Just had to create Player constructor and print the values